# Magento 2.0.2 mail not sending

Tags: magento2

All Mail is not sending from Magento 2.0.2. Mail function is enabled. I tested in index.php file. while testing the PHP mail function like mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers) mail is not sending. I am using Ubuntu server. Let me know anything we need to configure in my  php.ini file or any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set cron job first, because Magento does not send email without setting cron.

You can send email which is not Magento default email.But when you want to send all Magento default email like order email, shipment email, customer etc then you have set cron first.